# Centos kickstart installation without package location

Tags: centos7, kickstart

I want to install with unattended way Centos7 in a VM and at the moment I have to specify packages location in ks file and then in installation because is marked as error. Any way to install without specify them and unattended?

This is my ks file: https://gist.github.com/jngd/d436050371177b558efb

Comment: The URL in your kickstart gives a 404. Provide a link to a valid mirror.

Comment: And any way without provide any link?

Answer (score 1):

As Michael pointed out in his comment, you are using an invalid URL.  Because kickstart is unable to access that invalid site, the installation halts to ask you for a new installation source.

If you change that line to something like this:

url --url=http://mirrors.mit.edu/centos/7/os/x86_64/

...then it should work, and the installation can complete unattended.  You can see the full list of public mirrors and select a geographically close one for yourself here: http://www.centos.org/download/mirrors/